# How do I detect a specific word in C#

Tags: c#

I am not a coder or anything I am a noob at coding. I tried to do `Console.ReadLine("stop")` then `Console.End` but it doesn't work.

```
Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Cool! My Name Is Program Bot!");
Console.ReadLine("stop");
Console.End();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign to a variable and then check with conditionals

```
        Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Cool! My Name Is Program Bot!");
        var output = Console.ReadLine();
        if (output == null || output == "stop") {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

You need to check the following items in to understand what's what:

[if/else statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) -> Is how your code decides how to do something.

[c# variables](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_variables.asp) -> `var output` is a variable declaration which could also be `string output`

[c# methods](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.asp) -> `Console.ReadLine()` is a method that returns a string value

Comment: `output.Equals("stop")` needs to be changed to `output == "stop"` - in case `output` is `null`.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` will always return a string. Also check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1 `true if the value of a is the same as the value of b; otherwise, false. If both a and b are null, the method returns true.` No issue with Equals and null there.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras not true - if stdin is redirected (think `<` at the command-line) it returns `null` when the redirected stream ends. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline

Comment: @mjwills or `"stop".Equals(output)` 

Comment: @mjwillis since you don't want to loop forever: `if (output is null || output == "stop")` is probably more sensible

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1 - the quotation you found in the docs is **not** from the method you called (it is for a different `Equals` - those docs are for the `static` method - you aren't calling that). Test this for yourself - https://dotnetfiddle.net/8jGq7u . You can test this at the command line by pressing Ctrl-Z (to get `ReadLine` to return `null`).

Answer (score 2):

if you are interested in having the app continue until you ask it to stop, you can put everything in a "while" loop like this:

```
bool reachedEnd = false;

while (!reachedEnd) {
    Console.WriteLine ("What's your name?");
    string name = Console.ReadLine ();

    Console.WriteLine ("Cool! My Name Is Program Bot!");
    string endQuestion = Console.ReadLine ();
    if (endQuestion == "stop") {
        reachedEnd = true;
    }
}
```

in 99% of the cases there is not need to have:

> Environment.Exit(0);

because after the loop is finished there won't be any code left to execute so it will either exit or just hang until you close it yourself or with additional press of a key.
but you want it to close completely, you can add that after the loop and when the loop is finished it will terminate the app.

```
bool reachedEnd = false;

while (!reachedEnd) {
    Console.WriteLine ("What's your name?");
    string name = Console.ReadLine ();

    Console.WriteLine ("Cool! My Name Is Program Bot!");
    string endQuestion = Console.ReadLine ();
    if (endQuestion == "stop") {
        reachedEnd = true;
    }
}

Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Note: you should also exit if the line read is `null`, because that means EOF of a redirected input stream

Comment: Well traditionally, of course. It is even kind of annoying to the user to explicitly type "stop", but he said specific so that's what I gave him...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while` and until user do not enter `stop` your program is working.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = string.Empty;
        while (text != "stop")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Cool! My Name Is Program Bot!");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```